# Eliciting an "unrecognized command line option" from gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using gcc 7.3. If I compile e.g., `int main(){ }` with
`gcc main.c -Wno-foo`, the compilation succeeds and I get no error output.

Changing the source to `int main(){ int a[-1]; /*uncompilable*/ }` while maintaining the build command gets me:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:3:6: error: size of array ‘a’ is negative
  int a[-1];
      ^
main.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-foo’
```

Can I force the `unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-foo’` warning/error message without introducing a compilation error into the source?

`-Wfoo` (without the `no-`) gets me a warning message right away, but I'd rather keep the `no-` in there. (This is for compiler feature testing, which I do as part of my build.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a feature in gcc, not a bug. From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

> When an unrecognized warning option is requested (e.g.,
>   '-Wunknown-warning'), GCC emits a diagnostic stating that the option
>   is not recognized.  However, if the '-Wno-' form is used, the behavior
>   is slightly different: no diagnostic is produced for
>   '-Wno-unknown-warning' unless other diagnostics are being produced. 
>   This allows the use of new '-Wno-' options with old compilers, but if
>   something goes wrong, the compiler warns that an unrecognized option
>   is present.

So, if you need to know whether the option is present, you need to use it without the `no-` in there. Do that first; if you discover that it is supported, do whatever test you were going to do that required the `-Wno-foo` argument.